# Compute the exact value for the integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose that $f,g$ are integrable on $[0.5,2]$ and that $\int_.5^1x^k f(x)\,dx=\int_1^2x^kf(x)\,dx+2k^2=3+k^2$ for $k=0,1,2$ and compute the exact value for $$\int_0^{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}\frac{x^3}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \, dx$$

We went over this in class but I had no idea what is going and how to answer it

Comment: I guess you already tried the variable change $u = \sqrt{1-x^2}$. Yo should show us the result. To help us.

Comment: Im not sure what to do this was not covered in class

Comment: Well, Damien has just told you.Obviously you need to convert this integral to match the integrals you know. Since those involve $f(x)$, you need to have what in inside the function $f$ be the variable of integration. Your only hope is to do the change of variables and see what happens.